# Subquery with average and count in SQL

Tags: sql, count, subquery

Dears,
my data consists of following informations; customer ID, amount of transaction and counterparty region. For each region I would like to count average of volume of transactions. My idea is to use subqueries, but I stucked. This is my current idea, which does not work.

```
select avg(count_for_DK) from data where
(select count(amount) as count_for_DK, customer_id from data 
where country = 'DK'
group by customer_id, country 
order by customer_id asc)
```

Anyone please help me?

Screen with sample of my table:
https://ibb.co/BZXDL4Q

Comment: Please sample input table and desire output. It will be helpful to solve your problem. :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, sample of my input is added. My desire output should include one number with information about average of count of volume of transactions.

Comment: do not use picture, use plain text or table markdown to display tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to get customer wise average amount where country ='DK'
If this logic is what you are looking for then below query will work:

```
 select customer_id ,avg(amount) as average_for_DK from data 
    where country = 'DK'
    group by customer_id
    order by customer_id
```

If you want to get the average of number of transactions done by customers of country 'DK'

```
select avg(count_for_DK) from (
 select customer_id ,count(amount) as count_for_DK from data 
        where country = 'DK'
        group by customer_id
        order by customer_id) t
```

If you want to get the average of number of transactions done by customers of each country:

```
select country,avg(count_for_country) from (
 select country,customer_id ,count(amount) as count_for_country from data 
        
        group by country,customer_id
        order by country,customer_id) t
group by country
```

Comment: So close, there is a first step. Now I would like to have an average obtained from column "count_for_DK"

Comment: You want to have average of number of transaction per customer for a country?

Comment: Yes, average number of transactions done by customers for each country. To answer like: "customers make an average of 9 transactions with DK". I just did it in Excel so the result is 10,3, but now I should calculate it in SQL.

Comment: You are great Kazi, thank You so much. I got it. Wish You great rest of the day!

Comment: My pleasure. Best wishes.